# Is it possible to receive notifications for incoming email on Mac without Mail.app being open?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, notifications, gmail

I use the Gmail web page for email, but **I would like to receive Mac system notifications for incoming email**.

I don't want to enable notifications for Safari for lots of reasons, so I thought I'd just enable Mail alerts in System Settings.

However, it seems that this can only work when the Mail program is actually running. I can leave it open, but I'd rather not.

**Is there a way to get a simple notification for each new email (4 mailboxes) in macOS?**

I would prefer to avoid installing some kind of powerful and complicated program just to get email notifications.

Comment: Is your Mac based on Apple Silicon processor?

Comment: Are notifications allowed for mail.google.com website? System Prefs > Notifications > [click on website (mail.google.com)] > Allow notifications

Comment: It is an M1 Mac, and there are no websites listed under System Prefs › Notifications (I'm on Ventura).

Comment: So, you don't want to enable Notifications in Safari, in order to have Notifications from a webpage; and you don't want to install software either? That would rule out most options. What are your reasons for not wanting to use notifications?

Comment: I probably should enable notifications in Safari — it's just that websites are constantly asking to send notifications, and I sometimes click yes by mistake just because I'm in a hurry. If I enable them, I guess I'll have to clean up my act. Also (maybe you can answer) will I get Gmail notifications if there's no Gmail tab open?

Comment: I enabled Safari notifications in System Settings, and enabled mail.google.com in Safari Settings, but I'm still not getting any alerts. I quit all, restarted etc.